# VBA: Writing spelling suggestions next to spelling errors in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, spelling

In MS Word (Office for Mac 2016, version 15.31) I would like to enrich a document by marking spelling errors and by writing the first spelling suggestion next to each misspelled word: for example if the text says

**I wuld like to enrich**

the result I need is

**I [wuld][would] like to enrich**

I know that

```
iErrorCnt=Doc.This.SpellingErrors.Count
For J=1 to iErrorCnt
    Selection.TypeText Text:=DocThis.SpellingErrors(J)
Next J
```

will go through all spelling errors, and I know that

```
ActiveDocument.Words(1).GetSpellingSuggestions.Item(1).Name
```

allows to obtain the first spelling suggestion for a given word. But how do I link the misspelled word and the spelling suggestion (since the spelling suggestion is applied to words and words are indexed by integers) and how do I get them both marked in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub SpellCheck()
Dim Rng As Range, oSuggestions As Variant
For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
  With Rng
    If .GetSpellingSuggestions.Count > 0 Then
      Set oSuggestions = .GetSpellingSuggestions
      .Text = "[" & .Text & "][" & oSuggestions(1) & "]"
    Else
      .Text = "[" & .Text & "][]"
  End If
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please see an additional question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291205/visual-basic-for-ms-word-code-not-working-for-japanese