# Visual Basic for MS Word code not working for Japanese

Tags: vba, ms-word, spell-checking, cjk

I'm using the following VB code (authored by macropod, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877591/vba-writing-spelling-suggestions-next-to-spelling-errors-in-word)) inside MS Word (Word for Mac v16.16.21) to mark errors and insert the first spell checker suggestion inside a document:

```
Sub SpellCheck()
Dim Rng As Range, oSuggestions As Variant
For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
  With Rng
    If .GetSpellingSuggestions.Count > 0 Then
      Set oSuggestions = .GetSpellingSuggestions
      .Text = "[" & .Text & "][" & oSuggestions(1) & "]"
    Else
      .Text = "[" & .Text & "][]"
  End If
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

For English text it works fine: `This is some very important dokument` becomes `This is some very important [dokument][document]`.

But it doesn't work for Japanese: in the following sentence `それからバートわチャーリイこのかーどになにが見えるかといった。` there are two errors, the macro does nothing (even though Word marks the errors visually which means that the internal spell checker is aware of the errors: [image]

What am I doing wrong? Are the basic commands different for Japanese? How should I modify my script to get the expected result?

Comment: Thanks! How do I gather grammatical errors? I replaced `SpellingErrors` by `GrammaticalErrors` but nothing happened. Could you give me your code? What other kind of errors can one retrieve?

Comment: Word lacks any VBA correction suggestions for grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the errors comes up as a GrammaticalError, not a SpellingError here.

You can cycle through the GrammaticalErrors in a similar way to the code you already have, but there is no equivalent of the GetSpellingErrors method.

e.g. you can do

```
For Each Rng in ActiveDocument.Range.GrammaticalErrors
  ' Each GrammaticalError is just a Word Range, 
  ' It is not obvious exactly what the range "covers". Judging from your example
  ' the range "covers" the sentence.
  ' So do whatever you need here. This example just highlights each Rng
  Rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
End
```

There are only two types of ProofreadingError in the Word Object Model - wdGrammaticalError and wdSpellingError.